# Angular page doesnt refresh when data added/deleted

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular CRUD app with a list of subjects. I can add, delete and edit the subjects. My problem is that when I add or delete a subject, the page does not refresh with the new list of subjects. I've tried including `$route.reload();` but it gives me a console error:

ReferenceError: $route is not defined

Can anyone advise how to fix this error or a better way of refreshing the page?

HTML:

```
<h3>Add a Subject</h3>

 <div ng-controller="SubjectNewCtrl">
    <div class = "input-group">
<form name="newSubjectForm">
Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="subjects.name">
<br />

<a href="#/subjects"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></button></a>
 <a ng-click="createNewSubject()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Save Changes</a>

</form>
</div>

</div>
```

SubjectNewCtrl:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('SubjectNewCtrl', ['$scope', 'SubjectsFactory',  '$location',
    function ($scope, SubjectsFactory, $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'createNewSubject':

        $scope.createNewSubject = function () {
            SubjectsFactory.create($scope.subjects);
            $location.path('/subjects');

//This gives the console error
            $route.reload();
        }

    $scope.subjects = SubjectsFactory.query();

    }]);
```

EDIT- my routing in app.js

```
'use strict'


angular.module('myApp',
[
'ngRoute',
'ngResource',
'myApp.services',
'myApp.directives',
'myApp.controllers',
]);

angular.module('myApp')
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { 
$routeProvider.
  when('/subjects', {templateUrl: 'partials/subjects/subject-list.html', controller: 'SubjectCtrl'}).
  when('/subjects/new', {templateUrl: 'partials/subjects/subject-new.html', controller: 'SubjectNewCtrl'}).
  when('/subjects/:subjectid', {templateUrl: 'partials/subjects/subject-detail.html', controller: 'SubjectEditCtrl'}).
otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
.controller('SubjectNewCtrl', ['$scope', 'SubjectsFactory',  '$location', '$route',
function ($scope, SubjectsFactory, $location, $route) {

    // callback for ng-click 'createNewSubject':

    $scope.createNewSubject = function () {
        SubjectsFactory.create($scope.subjects);
        $location.path('/subjects');

//This gives the console error
        $route.reload();
    }

$scope.subjects = SubjectsFactory.query();

}]);
```

I add "$route" to your function

Comment: Thanks, this reloads the correct url but renders a blank page?

Comment: hmm... may be you try window.location="YOUR_URL" ?

Comment: $route.reload() creates new scope and you have blank page

Comment: and as I understand you should set new $route params and all $scope params

Comment: Can you elaborate on those comments further?

Comment: some where in $route should be installed controller that work with this view and template of this view.
You should set this variables after $route.reload() too.

Answer (score 2):

try to use **location.reload();**

example

```
        vm.deleteUser = function (id) {
        dataService.deletUser(id)
            .then(function () {
                location.reload();
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

use `scope.$apply` when updating the list of subjects do not force the whole page to reload...

```
$scope.createNewSubject = function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        SubjectsFactory.create($scope.subjects);
    });
};
```

btw. `$location.path('/subjects')` doesn't do anything if you are already on that page

Comment: I don't know what <code>SubjectsFactory.create($scope.subjects);</code> so maybe you need to refresh the scope variable after that method is completed

Comment: Have you considered to include ngRoute module, which is into a separate file? ` <script src="angular-route.js">` (into your html head)

Comment: @glepretre I have included ngRoute, it refreshes the page now as I added $route into my function parameters as per Kollley's answer above, however it gives me a blank page.

Comment: You have no error in console? You might need to configure your routes like [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this instead of reloading the route:

```
$scope.createNewSubject = function () {
    SubjectsFactory.create($scope.subjects).then(function (newSubject) {
        $scope.subjects = SubjectsFactory.query();  // [1]
    });
}
```

This version waits until the create request has completed before refetching the list of subjects (including the new subject), which will cause the view to refresh automatically.

In your code, you're reloading the current route/view immediately after initiating the create request without giving the create request a chance to complete, so the new subject actually doesn't exist yet.

[1] Alternatively, you might prefer to do `$scope.subjects.push(newSubject)` instead of refetching the list of subjects.